# how to create jni and Android.mk?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

hi i am new for android application can u tell me how to create jni and android.mk....i know jni purpose but how to create that jni in my project tell me step by step

Answer (score 0):

hi 
you'll need android NDK for this[NDK Documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html)

There is a very good tutorial there that'll help you get going